# Truncated callstack when debugging c++ mutex

Tags: c++, qt, mutex, callstack

In attempting to track down a blocked mutex, the callstack appears to be trunctated while waiting on the mutex. I don't see a normal call graph, just the following:

0   CpupSyscallStub wow64cpu        0x75132e09
1   Thunk0ArgReloadState    wow64cpu        0x75132bf1
2   RunCpuSimulation    wow64       0x751ad07e
3   Wow64LdrpInitialize wow64       0x751ac549
4   LdrpInitializeProcess   ntdll       0x77984956
5    ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'    ntdll       0x77981a17
6   LdrInitializeThunk  ntdll       0x7796c32e

This is blocking on a QMutex, I'm developing with Qt Creator using CDB from MSVC2008. I would like to be able to see a "normal" stack, that is a call graph up to the point of the mutex.lock() call.
If I had to guess, it would be related to debugging a 32 bit app on a 64 bit machine. Any ideas as how to get a proper callstack ?

Comment: Are you really looking at the correct thread?

Answer (score 0):

This link briefly touches on the problem. [Qt Windows Debugging](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Creator_Windows_Debugging)

It's not a Qt or Qt Creator specific issue. CDB.exe,  the windows command line debugger ( similar to GDB ), is built in two versions, 32 and 64 bit. When debugging a 32 bit app on a 32 bit CDB the application stack looks normal. When debugging a 32 bit app on a 64 bit CDB the stack gets obfuscated by the 32 bit emulator.